# React native custom timer works 10 times slower

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

UPD: Problem is solved. I just swapped setInterval to 1 sec instead of 1 ms. but i have no idea why it's not working with ms, if it's all mathematically allright. Thanks to commentators

There's my custom countdown Timer component (not ready). I have some problems with seconds counting. I've tried different ways to calculate seconds. Somewhy it's always works wrong.

```
class Timer extends Component{
  state = {
    playerTime : 3*60*1000, //initialize time with 3 minutes

    hours : ()=> {
      //did not tryed wait more than hour, but first countdown is well
      var hours = hours = Math.floor((this.state.playerTime/(1000*60*60))%24); 
      return hours;
    },
    minutes : () => {
      //minutes do countdown well
      var minutes = Math.floor((this.state.playerTime/(1000*60))%60);
      return minutes;
    },
    seconds : () => {
      // if divide by 100  seconds starts from 59, but after 0 goes 59 again, minutes do not countdown
      //if divide by 1000 its works in right way but in 10 times slower
      var seconds = Math.floor((this.state.playerTime/1000)%60);
      return seconds;
    },

  };

  render(){
    return(
      //create a button with black backround
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.playerButton} 
      onPress={() => { //start countdowning timer
        setInterval(() => {
          this.setState({playerTime : Number(this.state.playerTime-1)})
        } , 1)
      }}>
        <View justifyContent="center">
          <Text style={styles.timerText}> 
          {/*output a time in text format h:m:s */}
            {this.state.hours()}:
            {this.state.minutes()}:
            {this.state.seconds()}
          </Text>
        </View>

      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
};
```

I'm new in JS and React Native. Developing my own chess clock. Tell me please if you know some open-source js chess clocks

Comment: An interval delay of 1 means your function is going to run 1000 times per second in theory. That's not necessary at all.

Comment: How about setting the interval to 1 second?

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker ty, it works

Comment: Here's how to create a clock that won't fail: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-breeze-gg4l6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks to the bad answer down below I have to emphasize that *tracking time with an interval will not work reliably over longer periods of time*. This is for a chess clock, so using an interval to track time is most definitely out the window. This is also the reason why using an interval of 1 will absolutely not run the function exactly 1000 times per second. The bigger the interval is, the more precise it will be.

Answer (score 0):

First you should probably use function components, it's the right things to do for 99% of the use cases.

Also, hours, minutes and seconds should not be part of your state because you don't act on them directly. These are values that you are able to derive from the only state you need (playerTime).

Here is a working example (you will have to study the code a bit to see how it works and adapt for your case if you really want to use a class component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Timer = ({ initialTime }) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(initialTime);

  const start = () => {
    setInterval(() => setTime((time) => time - 1), 1000);
  };

  const hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
  const minutes = Math.floor((time - hours * 3600) / 60);
  const seconds = time - minutes * 60;

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={start}>
        Start countdown
      </button>
      <div>
        <h2>{time}</h2>
        {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Using a one second interval (or any interval) does not reliable track actual time.

Comment: Yes of course, but it's not really the point of the question.

Comment: Thanks for constructive criticism. I will try to follow your recommendations in next

Comment: I always stick to the question, I don't go into a rabbit hole. Feel free to give your own answer (don't forget to explain to him leap seconds).

Or maybe we can just help him out and let him figure out that time is not easy later if he needs to.

Comment: If the question is using a bad approach, answering it at face value is a bad idea, period. You are writing part of a FAQ, not posting in a chat.